# MethodNotAllowedHttpException laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes, resources

Why am I getting this error?

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
    Route::get('/',['uses'=>'Admin\IndexController@index','as'=>'adminIndex']);
    Route::resource('/products','Admin\ProductController');
});
```

Form:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => route('admin.products.edit',['products'=>$product->id]),'class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST']) !!}
                    {{ method_field('EDIT')}}
                    {!! Form::button('Edit', ['id'=>'submit','type'=>'submit']) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Also, when I'm trying to get list of routes by typing php artisan route:list, I'm getting error:

```
[Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException]
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your resource under admin prefix does not take the `admin` prefix. So you still have to use it without admin prefix. Besides, you are using 'url' instead of 'route'.

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin/products/'.$product->id.'/edit'),'class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST']) !!}
```

If you want to keep using route

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['products.edit', 'products'=>$product->id], 'class'=>'form-horizontal','method'=>'POST']) !!}
```

If you are tryint to update instead

```
{!! Form::model($product, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['products.update', $product->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal' ]) !!}
```

Comment: This will not work, since edit method uses GET, not POST.

Comment: Replace edit with update. If you are trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

Since edit method uses GET, change your code to:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['admin.products.edit', $product->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Edit', ['id' => 'submit']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Also, since it's GET, you can use simple link:

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.products.edit', $product->id) }}">
    <button class="btn" id="submit">Edit</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

look down should be use route 'as'=>'admin.products.edit' and get id also redirect to controller function edit products

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>'auth'],function(){


Route::get('/edit/{id}/product',
          [
            'uses'=>'Admin\IndexController@index',
            'as'=>'admin.products.edit'
          ]);

Route::resource('/products','Admin\ProductController');
});
```